# how to pick the first row in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to sort (ascending) based on a date column, and want to check the first row is in within a date range. So, i can makesure a particular file doesn't suits for the process.

```
eg: file A : contains July+August records

file B : contains September+October records
```

I want to pick `file B` only. If sorted based on date, fileA's first record will be  July record/August record.

After sorting how should i pick first record?

```
start, end = get_previous_month_start_end()
 df.sort_values('Document Date') <--pick first record from ascending order
            if not  df[df['Document Date'].between(start, end)]

                print ('This is not in the date range')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) with select first value by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) or [`Series.nsmallest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nsmallest.html) - it return one element Series, so also is necessary select by `iat`:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Document Date': rng, 'a':np.random.randint(10, size=10)}).sort_values('a')
print (df)
  Document Date  a
6    2017-04-09  0
7    2017-04-10  0
1    2017-04-04  2
2    2017-04-05  5
4    2017-04-07  6
8    2017-04-11  7
0    2017-04-03  8
3    2017-04-06  8
5    2017-04-08  8
9    2017-04-12  8

a = df['Document Date'].sort_values().iat[0]
print(a)
2017-04-03 00:00:00

a = df['Document Date'].nsmallest(1).iat[0]
print (a)
2017-04-03 00:00:00
```